# Dependency Inversion. Does it Apply to Objects like Lists, Windows Controls etc?

Tags: solid-principles

I recently started to learn about the SOLID Principles. I have a question about the "D" in SOLID. The Dependency Inversion Principle. I watched a Youtube Video from Tim Corey, where he explains, that anytime I use the "new" Keyword, it means tight coupeling and its bad.

Does that only apply on Classes that I created? or does it also apply to other things like System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem for Example. If so, what about Lists, StringBuilder etc?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) states that a high-level class must not depend upon a lower level class. They must both depend upon abstractions. And, secondly, an abstraction must not depend upon details, but the details must depend upon abstractions. This will ensure the class and ultimately the whole application is very robust and easy to maintain and expand

```
// Not following the Dependency Inversion Principle  
   
blic class SalaryCalculator  
 {  
     public float CalculateSalary(int hoursWorked, float hourlyRate) => hoursWorked * hourlyRate;  
 }  
  
 public class EmployeeDetails  
 {  
     public int HoursWorked { get; set; }  
     public int HourlyRate { get; set; }  
     public float GetSalary()  
     {  
         var salaryCalculator = new SalaryCalculator();  
         return salaryCalculator.CalculateSalary(HoursWorked, HourlyRate);  
     }  
 }
```

These classes do not follow the “Dependency Inversion Principle” as the higher-level class EmployeeDetails is directly depending upon the lower level SalaryCalculator class.
We can fix this issue as below:

```
// Following the Dependency Inversion Principle  
  
    public interface ISalaryCalculator  
    {  
        float CalculateSalary(int hoursWorked, float hourlyRate);  
    }  
  
    public class SalaryCalculatorModified : ISalaryCalculator  
    {  
        public float CalculateSalary(int hoursWorked, float hourlyRate) => hoursWorked * hourlyRate;  
    }  
  
    public class EmployeeDetailsModified  
    {  
        private readonly ISalaryCalculator _salaryCalculator;  
        public int HoursWorked { get; set; }  
        public int HourlyRate { get; set; }  
        public EmployeeDetailsModified(ISalaryCalculator salaryCalculator)  
        {  
            _salaryCalculator = salaryCalculator;  
        }  
        public float GetSalary()  
        {  
            return _salaryCalculator.CalculateSalary(HoursWorked, HourlyRate);  
        }  
    }
```

In the above code, we see that we have created an interface ISalaryCalculator and then we have a class called SalaryCalculatorModified that implements this interface. Finally, in the higher-level class EmployeeDetailsModified, we only depend upon the ISalaryCalculator interface and not the concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

I like to start from the perspective that since all of the SOLID principles are object-oriented, that means they apply to objects (with state *and* behavior) rather than to data structures (with only state) or abstract data types (whose only purpose is to convey state).

This means `List`, `StringBuilder`, etc. are excluded. Do note the DIP is more than simply "programming to an interface". You should still be declaring all of your variables as the most abstract types feasible, but that is not the DIP. You can have direct dependencies on data structures and ADTs.

Any class that you depend on for its behavior should have the dependency inverted. This includes the business logic you've written in other classes, as well as third-party services that you consume.